# Python mmh3: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-14: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I'm querying a DB for jokes and am getting back Python `str`s.  I want to use them as Unicode objects, so I do:

```
joke = unicode(joke, 'utf-8')
```

This works for all my DB results and does not cause any issues.

Then I try to hash each word in each joke like this:

```
result = mmh3.hash(joke)
```

and I get back:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I inspected the text and it's Japanese.  Does this mean I should drop all non-ascii characters before hashing or is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the complete error message. (As well as the value of `joke`.) It is not clear which function causes the error.

Comment: @DYZ I can't share the value, but it's Japanese text.  The type of that Japanese text is `unicode`.  As I mentioned, the `unicode(joke, 'utf-8')` function call works correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.hash(...)` function appears to require either `bytes` or `ascii`-convertible text.

The easiest way (if you're dealing entirely with `unicode` objects) is to convert them to `bytes` as you call `mmh3.hash`:

```
result = mmh3.hash(joke.encode('UTF-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  So just to be clear, I started with `str`, converted to `unicode` with a `utf-8` encoding, but now you're recommending I call `joke.encode('utf-8')`?  I feel like I'm misunderstanding something.  Thanks again!

Comment: The unicode sandwich :) -- It's best to use `unicode` inside your application and convert to binary types when interfacing with things that require bytes (network, `mmh3.hash`, etc.).  Note that I say `bytes` here, but in python2.x `bytes` is an alias for `str` (though really you should probably consider upgrading to python3 -- you're running out of time!).